# Determine required digits in each number place without looping

Tags: loops, math, numbers, range, numberformatter

Given a number range that starts with 1.0 and ends at 2.0, and steps every 0.25, if you printed it out (formatted), it would be 1.00; 1.25; 1.50; 1.75; 2.00; 2.25; etc...

**Without having to loop** through the range, how can I determine which digits will ever be needed in each place within the range? For example, that in the decimal 100th’s place, only the digits 0 and 5 will ever be needed? And in the decimal 10th’s place, only the digits 0, 2, 5, and 7 will ever be used? The solution would need to be able to support any range and step values.

Comment: For a computer program it's a *lot* easier to just try it and see.  You can determine within ten (10) steps every digit needed in every place.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: If you are asserting that every digit needed appears at least once in the first ten steps, that is clearly false. In the sequence from 0 to 462 with a step of 33, “2” does not appear in the tens position until step 13 (counting 0 as the zeroth step). If you are asserting something else, it is not clear what.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That wasn't what I was asserting, but I think that I was wrong either way so, "never mind..". :-)